# Problem while creating a new spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

In the **help.md** file it's telling me that JVM was changed from 11 to 17
this is what the help.md file looks like

```
The following was discovered as part of building this project:

* The JVM level was changed from '11' to '17', review the [JDK Version Range](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range) on the wiki for more details.
```

[and here is an example of later problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyFrW.png)

And even if i change the project structure manually to java 11 sdk
i have issues with versions next .

Comment: Spring Boot requires Java 17 not 11. So ofcourse you have issues when using Java 11 (that is also what the error is telling you).

Comment: Specifically Spring Boot 3.0.0. Older Spring Boot versions of course support Java 11 as well.

Comment: But spring boot supports other versions of java and this is the first time such a problem appear even though i made other projects with java 11 and 8

Comment: Spring 6/Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17. For older versions you need to stay at Spring 5.5 / Spring Boot 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is occurring in the newer version of Spring Boot. So when creating project using Spring Initializr or Spring Starter Project select the older version of Spring Boot (like `3.0.1` or `2.7.7`).

This should solve the problem.

[image: Here is a screenshot where you select the version]